# Modifying contextual filters to display user name

Tags: views

I have a view that takes one contextual filter for a UID. I would like to make the title of the page include the user name? My closest bet it the "Override title" option under "When the filter value is  in the URL or a default is provided". However, it appears that the only tokens available there are for the plain filter values, but I need the user name (as opposed to the UID). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `%1` does actually return the title.

Comment: It will provide the title (or user name, on a uid contextual filter) if you specify validation criteria. 

If you don't specify validation criteria, views will leave the value as the raw nid/uid.